# LiveEdit compile failed:

Tags: google-chrome, webpack, developer-tools, liveedit

I'm editing my code directly on the **Source** tab of Chrome's Developer Tools so I can test it. But recently this error started popping for me `LiveEdit compile failed:` and I'm almost certain that it is not a code error. The weird thing is that no error is specified. Does anyone ever had this problem?

[Developer Tools Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VctJA.png)

Comment: just remove and re-add the workspace.